# Is there an equivalent to Map unit in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography, units

I need to have points, lines and texts in ArcMap in map units like in QGIS so I can zoom to the feature and see it like it's a raster.

Is there anything I can do to manage that?

I use ArcMap 10.2.2

Comment: Switch to layout view, maybe?

Comment: That works but I need that in Data view. What PolyGeo works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard the functionality described that way before but I think what you are looking for is the help on [Working with data frame reference scales](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/working-with-data-frame-reference-scales.htm):

> You can set a reference scale for your data frame, which fixes the
>   size for symbols and text to draw at the desired height and width at
>   the referenced map scale. This is like freezing the symbol and text
>   sizes used in your data frame. One reason to set a reference scale is
>   if you want the detail in your data frame to look the same on-screen
>   as when you print it. It's useful to see the map's symbols on-screen
>   at the size they will appear in the printed copy.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to map units is "unknown units".  The setting is located in the menu bar.  View> Data Frame Properties > General (tab) and set to "unknown"